# Flutter - iOS crash: 'FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (no such file)

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase

It's a Flutter application. Android is running fine but iOS after a successful build while launching gets an exception 'FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (no such file).

```
dyld[3261]: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises
  Referenced from: <5F72BA8B-8D2A-308D-A8C7-D03C4EFC9145> /Users/tapas/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3E0C59C5-E4F8-42C9-8326-A50CDF72B309/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/1765304E-7706-4163-8F3C-9850E68D36B5/Sample App.app/Sample App
  Reason: tried: '/Users/tapas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bngnmhrnlcjictefmiowbubldvkv/Build/Products/Debug-dev-iphonesimulator/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/Users/tapas/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3E0C59C5-E4F8-42C9-8326-A50CDF72B309/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/1765304E-7706-4163-8F3C-9850E68D36B5/Sample App.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (no such file), '/Users/tapas/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3E0C59C5-E4F8-42C9-8326-A50CDF72B309/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/1765304E-7706-4163-8F3C-9850E68D36B5/Sample App.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (no such file), '/Users/tapas/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3E0C59C5-E4F8-42C9-8326-A50CDF72B309/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/1765304E-7706-4163-8F3C-9850E68D36B5/Sample App.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/Users/tapas/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3E0C59C5-E4F8-42C9-8326-A50CDF72B309/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/1765304E-7706-4163-8F3C-9850E68D36B5/Sample App.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (no such file), '/Users/tapas/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3E0C59C5-E4F8-42C9-8326-A50CDF72B309/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/1765304E-7706-4163-8F3C-9850E68D36B5/Sample App.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (no such file), '/Users/tapas/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3E0C59C5-E4F8-42C9-8326-A50CDF72B309/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/1765304E-7706-4163-8F3C-9850E68D36B5/Sample App.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' (no such file)
```

I know this similar issue already has good answers but unfortunately, those didn't work for me. Looking for your help.